# PHP7 MongoDB - create index

Tags: php, mongodb

I'm moving a php script that create index in mongo from php5 to php7.

I tried to use the following MongoDB\Driver\Command but it returns this error.

Anyone know how to create index to an existing collection?

```
$index = ['id' => 1, 'user' => 1, 'time' => 1];
$cmd = new MongoDB\Driver\Command([
     'createIndexes' => $collection_name, 
     'indexes' => $index
]);
$mongo_client->executeCommand($mongo_database, $cmd);
```

PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught MongoDB\Driver\Exception\RuntimeException: no such cmd: createIndexes

Comment: Can you confirm what version of MongoDB server you are connecting to (for example, with the output of `db.version()` in the `mongo` shell)? Also, what version of the PHP driver are you using? The `createIndexes` command was added in MongoDB 2.6, so if you are connecting to an older version of MongoDB this error would be expected if you are trying to call the command directly.

Comment: Generally it is better to use the driver API rather than the underlying command as this abstracts some of the server differences. For a single index use  [`MongoDB\Collection::createIndex`](https://docs.mongodb.com/php-library/current/reference/method/MongoDBCollection-createIndex/); for an array of indexes use [`MongoDB\Collection::createIndexes`](https://docs.mongodb.com/php-library/current/reference/method/MongoDBCollection-createIndexes/).

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure if you solved it already but i have found solution:

```
 $manager = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017");
 $command = new MongoDB\Driver\Command([
    "createIndexes" => "collectionName",
    "indexes"       => [[
      "name" => "indexName",
      "key"  => [ "keyName" => 1],
      "ns"   => "databaseName.collectionName",
   ]],
]);
$result = $manager->executeCommand("databaseName", $command);
```

Credits to: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-driver/issues/170

Also you can add index options like `unique` or `expireAfterSeconds` inside:

```php
$command = new MongoDB\Driver\Command([
        "createIndexes" => "collectionName",
        "indexes"       => [[
          "name" => "indexName",
          "key"  => [ "keyName" => 1],
          "ns"   => "databaseName.collectionName",
          "unique" => true,
          // "expireAfterSeconds" => 300
       ]],
    ]);
```

Comment: Also if you want any index options like `unique` or `expireAfterSeconds` you should put them in the index args inside **indexes array**. Example: `"indexes" => [["name" => "indexName", ... , "unique" => true]]`